# Swift 3: String search backwards

Tags: swift, string, indexing, reverse

I want to search backwards in a string. But all examples I found are not running on current Swift 3.0. ".BackwardsSearch" is not an option available on my XCode 8. Any idea, how this can be done?
Example:

```
let rPos = rIndex(sourceString, searchString)
```

or

```
let rPos = sourceString.rindex(of: searchString)
```

Comment: `static var backwards: NSString.CompareOptions` with `func range(of aString: String, options mask: String.CompareOptions = default, range searchRange: Range<String.Index>? = default, locale: Locale? = default) -> Range<String.Index>?`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XCode autocomplete will suggest this:

```
let rpos = sourceString.range(of:searchString, options:String.CompareOptions.backwards, range:nil, locale:nil)
```

However, range and locale have defaults of nil, so you can omit them:

```
let rpos = sourceString.range(of:searchString, options:String.CompareOptions.backwards)
```

And `options` is of the type `String.CompareOptions` so you only need the last part:

```
let rpos = sourceString.range(of:searchString, options:.backwards)
```

(Thanks @MartinR for pointing out the shortened versions)

Comment: Or just `sourceString.range(of: searchString, options: .backwards)`

Comment: Thanks! Take this also.